# How to not commit Google adSense app id to version control

Tags: ios, git, admob

In https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist it is required to add your App ID to your app's Info.plist. Is there a way to reference an outside source directly in the Info.plist or initialize any other way? I'd prefer not to commit the App ID to git.
Earlier you could initialize with `configure(withApplicationID:)`, but this is deprecated in favor of `[GADMobileAds.sharedInstance startWithCompletionHandler:]` which doesn't take an app id as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the way that one handles creating files like this is by generating them during build. You can put the app ID in a file which is ignored by Git (using your `.gitignore`) and version the mostly complete `info.plist` file. Then, you can generate the final `info.plist` file during the build by using both source files.

If your build step happens during a CI process, you can store the app ID in an encrypted secret, which most CI platforms support, and build by pulling the value from the environment instead of a file on disk.